# Changing from curr.next to curr gives me nullpointerException. Why?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null, singly-linked-list

The entire code was like following:

```
public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {        
    ListNode dummyHead = new ListNode(0);
    ListNode curr = dummyHead, p = l1, q = l2;
    int carry = 0;
    int sum;

    while(p != null || q != null){
        int x = (p != null)? p.val:0;
        int y = (q != null)? q.val:0;

        sum = x + y + carry;
        carry = sum/10;
        curr.next = new ListNode(sum%10); // What if I change it to curr.val = sum%10?
        curr = curr.next;

        if(p != null) p = p.next;
        if(q != null) q = q.next;
    }

    if(carry > 0){

        curr.next = new ListNode(carry);

    }        
    return dummyHead.next; // If the change I made above works, then I just return dummyHead            
}
```

I was just wondering why not just using `curr.val = sum%10` instead of `curr.next = new ListNode(sum%10)`? And then in the end, instead of returning `dummyHead.next`, we can return `dummyHead` itself, sounds reasonable right? So I made the change but I got a nullpointerException. Why? How come dummyHead or curr is ever null? So basically what I was trying to do is that in each iteration I work out the sum and then assign it to curr.val, and then curr changes to next, so on and so forth.

Comment: To me it is clear that the intention of the code is to add the result of the addition to the list as new node(s) rather than updating the existing ones. So if you want to completely change the intention of the method then it becomes a complete new one so maybe you should write your own method instead. Regarding the null pointer it is pretty simple, curr is a new node not in the list yet so curr.next is null which means  `curr = curr.next` will make curr null

Comment: Where is your class ListNode comes from? There is no such class in standard JDK. To check why you get a NPE it's usefull to know what is going inside of ListNode.

Comment: and if you change your code from
`curr.next = new ListNode(sum%10); curr = curr.next;`     
to  `curr.val = new ListNode(sum%10); curr.next = new ListNode(0); curr = curr.next;` then you'll be able to use curr.val

Comment: I see. In the first iteration, there won't be any problem because basically I'm just changing the head's value. But in the second iteration, since curr is equal to null, and I can't perform value assignment on a null. I was only looking at the first iteration and ignored the iterations after it, a silly mistake! Thank you!